# Need to flush/clear when updating a big list of objects with Hibernate + Spring Data?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, flush

i use hibernate with Spring Data and I have a list of 'Product' objects.
i recover from a 'service' layout this list.
my list is big, not very big, but big.
i use springdata so the autoimplemented method called 'saveAll'.
so, i wanna use dao.saveAll(products) tu update/persist this big list.
The question is :
do i have to clear and flush (at each n objects'step), as i handle a big list of Product ?
or is it implemented in Springdata ?
And if yes, how to do that ?
what is the best practice to do that ?

Comment: Yes you need to `clear` and `flush` and no there is nothing automatically implemented in Spring Data JPA for that.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the application logic. If it only makes sense to update all or nothing, you need to update the list in a single transaction. If this is not desired, e.g. batch processing scenarios where the list is processed in chunks, you can manually `flush()` after each chunk.

Manual `clear()` and `flush()` can be used to improve the performance in some cases, but first and foremost your program must be correct. You can take a look at [The best way to do batch processing with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) tutorial if you want to go this route.

Comment: @kdowbecki ok Karol. My need is to update absolutly the whole list i recover by the service layout (Product products = service.recoverAll();) and with no exception. So, with a big list do i have to trust the quality of springdata+hibernate implementation of 'saveAll()' method ? Or, do i have to build n mini list and to update each mini list ? (1/ List miniList1(AND) 2/ for object 1 to 50 --> list1.add(product) (AND THEN) 3/ dao.saveAll(miniList1);) –

Comment: @electrode what the final solution you implemented?